# Twitter bootstrap responsive utilities

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide a div on medium screen size (and below). I've read that you can use [Bootstrap's responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) - `.hidden-md-down`, but this class is not found in my CSS (that I downloaded from getbootstrap.com).

I tried customizing my download to include only the Responsive utilities from the CSS section or to download all available options and none of the archives contains `.css` file with such class.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `.hidden-md-down` is supposed to be, but the correct class is `.hidden-md` (as per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)). `.hidden-md` will hide the element on what Bootstrap defines as *Medium Devices* - devices between 992px and 1199px width. It will not, however, hide the element on *Small* or *Extra Small* devices.

If you want to hide the element on *Medium* devices and below, you'd be better off using `.visible-lg-{displayType}`, where `{displayType}` is either `block`, `inline` or `inline-block` (e.g. `.visible-lg-block`).

[image: Table from Bootstrap's Documentation]

Comment: Oh, damn, my bad. Last time I used bootstrap it was for a client that demanded using the alpha version of bootstrap 4. Which replaces those class: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classes `.hidden-md`, `.hidden-sm` and `.hidden-xs` together. I've not heard of the one you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Update your bootstrap version to 4 : [Bootstrap V4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)